# python `for i in iter` vs `while True; i = next(iter)`

Tags: python, iteration

To my understanding, both these approach work for operating on every item in a generator:

- let `i` be our operator target
- let `my_iter` be our generator
- let callable `do_something_with` return `None`

#### While Loop + StopIteratioon

```
try:
    while True:
        i = next(my_iter)
        do_something_with(i)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

#### For loop / list comprehension

```
for i in my_iter:
    do_something_with(i)
```

```
[do_something_with(i) for i in my_iter]
```

*Minor Edit: `print(i)` replaced with `do_something_with(i)` as suggested by @kojiro to disambiguate a use case with the interpreter mechanics.*

---

As far as I am aware, these are both applicable ways to iterate over a generator, Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Right now the for loop is looking superior to me. Due to: less lines/clutter and readability in general, plus single indent.

I really only see the while approach being advantages if you want to handily break the loop on particular exceptions.

Comment: Does readability count? The for-loop/list-comprehension is far easier on the eyes

Comment: As others have said, the list comprehension is not appropriate. For that matter, doing `print` multiple times over a single iterator without doing anything else is wrong. I realize this is probably just an example, but don't forget you can do things like `print('\n'.join(iter))`. If `iter` does not contain strings, `print('\n'.join(map(str, iter)))`

Comment: @kojiro Point noted, Indeed `print()` was a placeholder for the example, can you recommend a better placeholder that doesn't allow confusing about the intent of the question? putting `pass` statements in just didn't feel right in authoring.

Comment: @ThorSummoner You could always use that classic function `do_something_with(name)` to make it clear that what is done isn't salient to the question, but helpers should be clear that _something_ is done.

Comment: @kojiro if indeed `print` wasn't just a main place holder, then `print(*my_iter, sep='\n')` would also be viable (in 3.x or 2.6+ with a  future import)

Comment: @JonClements yeah, that's much better.

Answer (score 5):

the third option is definitively *NOT* the same as the first two.  the third example creates a list, one each for the return value of `print(i)`, which happens to be `None`, so not a very interesting list.

the first two are semantically *similar*.   There is a minor, technical difference;  the while loop, as presented, does not work if `my_iter` is not, in fact an iterator (ie, has a `__next__()` method); for instance, if it's a `list`.  The for loop works for all iterables (has an `__iter__()` method) in addition to iterators.

The correct version is thus:

```
my_iter = iter(my_iterable)
try:
    while True:
        i = next(my_iter)
        print(i)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Now, aside from readability reasons, there in fact *is* a technical reason you should prefer the for loop;  there is a penalty you pay (in CPython, anyhow) for the number of bytecodes executed in tight inner loops.  lets compare:

```
In [1]: def forloop(my_iter):
   ...:     for i in my_iter:
   ...:         print(i)
   ...:         

In [57]: dis.dis(forloop)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 27)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (my_iter)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                16 (to 26)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  3          13 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             16 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             22 POP_TOP
             23 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   26 POP_BLOCK
        >>   27 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

7 bytecodes called in inner loop vs:

```
In [55]: def whileloop(my_iterable):
   ....:     my_iter = iter(my_iterable)
   ....:     try:
   ....:         while True:
   ....:             i = next(my_iter)
   ....:             print(i)
   ....:     except StopIteration:
   ....:         pass
   ....:     

In [56]: dis.dis(whileloop)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (iter)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (my_iterable)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (my_iter)

  3          12 SETUP_EXCEPT            32 (to 47)

  4          15 SETUP_LOOP              25 (to 43)

  5     >>   18 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (next)
             21 LOAD_FAST                1 (my_iter)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             27 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

  6          30 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
             33 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             36 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             39 POP_TOP
             40 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           18
        >>   43 POP_BLOCK
             44 JUMP_FORWARD            18 (to 65)

  7     >>   47 DUP_TOP
             48 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (StopIteration)
             51 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             54 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       64
             57 POP_TOP
             58 POP_TOP
             59 POP_TOP

  8          60 POP_EXCEPT
             61 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 65)
        >>   64 END_FINALLY
        >>   65 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             68 RETURN_VALUE
```

9 Bytecodes in the inner loop.

We can actually do even better, though.

```
In [58]: from collections import deque

In [59]: def deqloop(my_iter):
   ....:     deque(map(print, my_iter), 0)
   ....:     

In [61]: dis.dis(deqloop)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (deque)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (map)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (my_iter)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             21 POP_TOP
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

everything happens in C, `collections.deque`, `map` and `print` are all builtins. (for cpython) so in this case, there are no bytecodes executed for looping.  This is only a useful optimization when the iteration step is a c function (as is the case for `print`.  Otherwise, the overhead of a python function call is larger than the `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` overhead.

Comment: very insightful and knowledgeable/scientific answer! Are there any quirks particular to using map inside a deque operation? (I'll assume not, unless corrected)

Comment: @ThorSummoner: well, like I said, there's a small performance bonus to using the `deque(map(...))` version when the mapped over function is a c function; and a corresponding *large penalty* when it's a python function.  Other than that, not really anything for it;  It's also (probably) not any better at all in, say pypy.  Prefer the for loop unless you have a really good reason.

Answer (score 3):

The for loop is the most pythonic. Note that you can break out of for loops as well as while loops.

Don't use the list comprehension unless you need the resulting list, otherwise you are needlessly storing all the elements. Your example list comprehension will only work with the print function in Python 3, it won't work with the print statement in Python 2.

Comment: Ah thanks for that point about list comprehension storing the operation results. Such overhead is something I very quickly overlook when tinkering.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with you that the `for` loop is superior. As you mentioned it is less clutter and it is a lot easier to read. Programmers like to keep things as simple as possible and the `for` loop does that. It is also better for novice Python programmers who might not have learned `try/except`. Also, as Alasdair mentioned, you can break out of for loops. Also the `while` loop runs an error if you are using a list unless you use `iter()` on `my_iter` first.

Comment: Just for _programmers like to keep things as simple as possible_, +1. I'm not sure it's true, but it made me think.